# How can I use core's WebP support instead of the WebP module?

Tags: media, 9

According to the [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/3171135), Drupal 9.2 supports WebP for better image compression.

I've been using the [WebP module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webp) on my 9.1 site to serve WebP images, but it has a [performance-killing bug](https://www.drupal.org/project/webp/issues/3177103) and I would like to use Core if possible.

So when I upgrade to 9.2, **how can I replace the WebP module with core's WebP support?**

I upgraded to 9.2, uninstalled WebP, and searched for WebP options, but couldn't find anything.

This [Lullabot post](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/speed-drupals-front-end-webp-images) said it should be supported in the **Convert** effect, but I don't see the option.

Answer (score 8):

WebP is supported in the GD image toolkit.

As noted in the change record, you can check whether your version of PHP has WebP support by going to `admin/reports/status/php#module_gd`.

### What if I am using Imagemagick?

If you do a lot of image processing on your site, you may be using the ImageMagick toolkit via the [ImageMagick contrib module](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagemagick).  In this case, it doesn't matter if the GD support is enabled because Drupal is using Imagemagick, not GD.

So first, check your image toolkit at `/admin/config/media/image-toolkit`.  If you are using ImageMagick, you need to do the following:

1. Click **Image formats** accordion title on `/admin/config/media/image-toolkit`.
2. In **Enable/disable image formats**, scroll down to **WEBP** and set `enabled: true`.
3. Save.

This will now let you convert to WebP for your image styles. (`/admin/config/media/image-styles`)

### What if I am using responsive images?

**If you are using responsive image styles on your site via the core **Responsive Image** module, and you convert all your image styles to WebP, you will break support for older versions of Safari and Internet Explorer, which do not support WebP.**  ([caniuse webP](https://caniuse.com/webp))

This is something the WebP module handles automatically, but core does not.  So if you convert everything to WebP and call it a day, you will break your site for some users.

Unfortunately, core's Responsive Image module only supports breakpoints based on viewport size, but the correct approach is to set the `type` on the tag, which core does not allow you to do. There is a [drupal.org issue about this](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3213491).

Workarounds:

- Use the [WebP](https://www.drupal.org/project/webp) or [ImageOptimize WebP](https://www.drupal.org/project/imageapi_optimize_webp) modules instead of core.
- For each responsive image style (`/admin/config/media/responsive-image-style/MY_STYLE`), use image styles converted to WebP for all the breakpoints, and then use a non-WebP image style as the **Fallback image style**.

Comment: Note regarding the performance that there is a patch ready, and my aim would be to merge it in the next few days and get a stable release ASAP