# Can't add an image extension to the field_image of the Article content type

Tags: 8, nodes, media

I need to upload an image with the `webp` extension and add it as the main image of a content item with the "Article" content type. Since its `field_image` doesn't have the `webp` extension by default, I've added the extension to the "Allowed file extensions" input at the managing tab of the `field_image`.

When I check the row with the `name='field.field.node.article.field_image'` in the `config` DB table, I see that the extension was successfully added to the `data` array under the keys `['settings']['file_extensions']`.

But when I try to upload and add an image with the `webp` extension on the editing page of the article I still receives the error that only png, gif, jpg and jpeg are allowed.

How to resolve the problem?

ps. Drupal 8.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 8.7 does not support WebP.

You can:

- Upgrade to Drupal 9.2+, which supports WebP (recommended, [see more info in this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/303881/how-can-i-use-cores-webp-support-instead-of-the-webp-module/303882#303882))
- Use the [WebP module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webp)
- Use the [ImageAPI Optimize WebP module](https://www.drupal.org/project/imageapi_optimize_webp) (more complicated to set up than WebP module but lets you do complicated chains of processing if you have a site that needs to do a lot of work with images)